# When converting a NSString to a char* using UTF8String, how to retain it?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management

When converting a NSString to a char* using UTF8String, how to retain it?

According to the following link, when you use  UTF8String the returned char* is pretty much autoreleased, so it won't last beyond the current function:   http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#jumpTo_128

It says i have to copy it or something to keep it around. How can i do this?

The reason i ask is that if i do [myCharPointer retain] it doesn't retain it because it's not an obj-c object, it's a c pointer.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `strdup()`

```
const char* utf8Str = [@"an example string" UTF8String];
if (utf8Str != NULL) 
{
    stringIWantToKeep = strdup(utf8Str);
}
```

When you are done with `stringIWantToKeep`, you free it as though it was originally malloc'd.

Answer (score 2):

Try using [-getCString:maxLength:encoding:](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/getCString:maxLength:encoding:), e.g.:

```
NSUInteger bufferCount = sizeof(char) * ([string length] + 1);
const char *utf8Buffer = malloc(bufferCount);
if ([string getCString:utf8Buffer 
             maxLength:bufferCount 
              encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]) {
    NSLog("Success! %s", utf8Buffer);
    free(utf8Buffer); // Remember to do this, or you will get a memory leak!
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't i need to malloc +1 byte for the null terminator?

Comment: Caution! While this won't ever crash, if your original NSString contains UNICODE characters (outside of the standard ASCII set) you'll only get a partial string in your utf8Buffer.  [string length] returns the number of UNICODE characters in the buffer, which is smaller than the size needed to render it in UTF8.  Use [string lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]; to get the actual length.

Answer (score 0):

If you need an object to retain/release as every other object you can do the following:

```
NSData* storage= [yourNSString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
char* yourCString= (char*)storage.bytes;
// your code flow here
```

Now you can pass both `storage` and `yourCString` to any function retaining/releasing storage as you like, when the retain count of `storage` will go to 0 the memory pointed by `yourCString` will be freed too.

I used this to keep a single copy of a very long string while having references created by `strtok_r` in beans and have the memory released only when all beans had been released.

#### A little note about (missing) BOM:

As stated here http://boredzo.org/blog/archives/2012-06-03/characters-in-nsstring `dataUsingEncoding:` should add BOM but i've checked with the debugger and **there is no BOM** in the returned bytes.